# PHP regex - ignore multiple spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently working on a simple PHP template engine and want to replace all

```
{% include file="anotherTemplate.tpl" %}
```

with the content of the given template. For this task, I use regular expressions.

```
private $funcSeparatorL = '{%';
private $funcSeparatorR = '%}';

// ...

preg_match('/' . $this->funcSeparatorL . ' include file="(.*)\.(.*)" ' . $this->funcSeparatorR . '/', $this->content)
```

This works fine but obviously only with a single space between the separator and the content in-between. I want to be able to use multiple spaces to make the whole thing more error resistant.

But if I use `.*` to match multiple characters, the whole page loads forever and never finishes.

```
preg_match('/' . $this->funcSeparatorL . '.*include file="(.*)\.(.*)".*' . $this->funcSeparatorR . '/', $this->content)
```

Is `.*` the proper way to handle such a task and if yes, why does it lead to such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.*`, just use `\s*`. That just matches spaces and avoids [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), which is the reason for your current problem.

Example:

```
preg_match('/' . $this -> funcSeparatorL . '\s*include file="(.*)\.(.*)".*' . $this -> funcSeparatorR . '/', $this -> content);
```

As an aside, you can improve your whole regex further by getting rid of all those other `.*`s, too, or making them non-greedy when possible. Untested example:

```
preg_match('/' . $this -> funcSeparatorL . '\s*include file="([^"]*?)\.([^"]*)".*?' . $this -> funcSeparatorR . '/', $this -> content);
```

[Here's a demo](http://ideone.com/WALdQq).

You can probably improve this further by replacing the last `.*?` with `[^}]*`, but that depends on whether you allow nested template expressions.

Rule of thumb: if you type `.+` or `.*` without a non-greedy qualifier (`?`), odds are very high you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately neither of the examples did work. :/

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working? Note that preg_match doesn't do replacements, just matching. You need preg_replace instead.

Comment: Sure, I use `preg_match` inside a while loop and echo something out for each occurrence. With my first approach, it echoes for every include in the file, but with your example, it's not matching the includes.